# Display or not an option parameter according to another option parameter

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 option parameters choice_1 and choice_2

I'm looking for a way but I didn't find that when I choose 'B' from choice_1 then 'D' from choice_2 is not displayed

```
 choice_1 = input.string(title="Choice 1", defval="A", options=["A", "B", 'C'])
 choice_2 = input.string(title="Choice 2", defval="D", options=["D", "E", 'F'])
```

Is there a way to work around it?

I tried to do it but of course it doesn't work.

```
 choice_1 = input.string(title="Choice 1", defval="A", options=["A", "B", 'C'])

if choice_1 == 'B'
    choice_2 = input.string(title="Choice 2", defval="D", options=["E", 'F'])
else
    choice_2 = input.string(title="Choice 2", defval="D", options=["D", "E", 'F'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible.

What you can do is, you can throw a runtime error when `B` from `choice_1` and `D` from `choice_2` are selected.

```
choice_1 = input.string(title="Choice 1", defval="A", options=["A", "B", 'C'])
choice_2 = input.string(title="Choice 2", defval="D", options=["D", "E", 'F'])

if ((choice_1 == "B") and (choice_2 == "D"))
    runtime.error("You cannot select 'D' from choice 2")
```

[image]